# Changing fluently brightness of QPushButton icon

Tags: qt, brightness, qpushbutton, qicon

I found a function to make QImage brighter and used in my Qt application.
I want to show simple "animation" of making button step by step brighter and than again step by step back to initial state after user click it.

Here my code:

```
void Widget::on_stopButton_clicked(){

    player.stop();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i){

        QImage* image = new QImage(":/Graphics/Graphics/StopButton.png");
        changeBrightness(*image, i);
        QPixmap* pixmap = new QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*image));
        ui->stopButton->setIcon(QIcon(*pixmap));
        QThread::msleep(50);

    } 

}
```

It doesn't work as I expected... 
I see only the final effect, so the last call:
changeBrightness(*image, 50);

It seems that user can see changes on form only after function ends, is it right?
Is there other way to make such "animation"?

Comment: You don't need to create `QImage` and `QPixmap` with new operator. You may create instances on stack. Both are supports COW.

Comment: I'll change this, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give Qt any time to redraw the widget after you update the button's image, because you are stuck in the loop. Only after you finished updating the image, Qt will be able to redraw your widget, which is why you only see the final result.

Look into [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). You can set its timeout to 50 milliseconds via QTimer::setInterval. Then connect a slot that changes the color of the button's image to QTimer::timeout. This slot will be much like your code, but without the loop. E.g. each call of the slot is a single iteration of your loop. Finally, to start or stop the animation, you call QTimer::start or QTimer::stop.

Comment: Cool, thanks again :) Music Player is still "growing" ;)

Comment: @WJuz The important lesson here is, Qt GUI is *single-threaded*. It means, when this single GUI thread is executing your slot or event handler method, it will not be doing anything else (such as reacting to user, updating the screen, doing network stuff). This means, you must never block the event loop by waiting/sleeping/doing long calculation (<16 ms for a "real-time" interactive app like a game, something like a few hundred ms for normal desktop app). Use other mechanisms, like `QTimer` suggested here, if you need to wait for a moment.

Comment: Thank You all, the efect is quite nice... just right what I wanted  
http://www.mediafire.com/download/992zmc582ppc8t9/Nagywanie_2016_08_26_17_25_12_437.mp4    :D

Comment: @hyde It doesn't matter much that Qt is single-threaded. Such blocking code blocks the event loop in the thread where it runs. If it happens to be the GUI thread, the GUI won't work, that's understandable. The OP could run it in another thread, and then it'd work fine. Of course this is a horrible waste of a thread for such simple code, and he'd need to make thread-safe calls via e.g. `invokeMethod`, but in principle this problem has nothing to do with Qt being single-threaded. You could have a multithreaded GUI on Windows (the only platform where it's supported) and it still wouldn't work.